# Testing basic async http request in Node with Got, Nock & Chai

Tags: javascript, node.js, nock, node.js-got

I am trying to figure out why my unit test is not working correctly. It seems that the external network request is made despite my using Nock to intercept my http request.

I have a very basic `getUser` service, getuser-got.js:

```js
    const got = require('got');
    
    module.exports = {
      getUser(user) {
        return got(`https://api.github.com/users/${user}`)
        .then(response=>JSON.parse(response.body))
        .catch(error => console.log(error.response.body))
      }
    };
```

This can be called succesfully but I want a unit test for it.

Here's my code in a file named `getuser-got.test.js`:

```js
    const getUser = require('../getuser-got').getUser;
    
    const expect = require('chai').expect;
    const nock = require('nock');
    
    const user_response = require('./response');
    
    describe('GetUser-Got', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {
        nock('https//api.github.com')
        .get('/users/octocat')
        .reply(200, user_response);
      });
      it('Get a user by username', () => {
        return getUser('octocat')
          .then(user_response => {
            // expect an object back
            expect(typeof user_response).to.equal('object');
            // test result of name and location for the response
            expect(user_response.name).to.equal('The Octocat')
            expect(user_response.location).to.equal('San Francisco')
          })
      });
    });
```

The file named `response` contains a copy of the expected response from the Github API, which I am loading into the `user_response` variable. I have replaced the values for `name` and `location` in order to make my test fail.

```js
    module.exports = {
        login: 'octocat',
    ...
        name: 'The FooBar',
        company: '@github',
        blog: 'https://github.blog',
        location: 'Ssjcbsjdhv',
    ...
    }
```

The problem is that I can see that Nock is not intercepting my request. When I run the test it continues to make an actual call to the external API. The test therefore passes, because it is not using my local `response` as the return value.

I've tried adding in `nock.disableNetConnect();` but this just causes the test to timeout, as it's clearly still trying to make the external call. If I run my test I get:

```
➜  nock-tests npm test

> nock-tests@1.0.0 test /Users/corin/Projects/nock-tests
> mocha "test/test-getuser-got.js"



  GetUser-Got
    ✓ Get a user by username (290ms)


  1 passing (296ms)
```

What am I doing wrong to not have Nock intercept my http request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value being passed to the `nock` function is not a valid URL, it's missing the colon in the schema.

Updating it to `nock('https://api.github.com')` gets the test to fail locally, as desired.

Comment: Oh ****, so embarrassing. I need a unit-test to check my own syntax errors, obviously. Thank you for the spot.